# multiple filters in AngularJS with text and radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, filter, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat, textinput

I'm doing a search module on a table. The search (text field) on the table is working. There are equally sorts on column header of the table.

I would like to add radio button under the search text field for improving my search (add filter).Hence the search will be based on the text entered for the field chosen.

***Here my view:***

```
<div class="spacer input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText" class="form-control" placeholder="Search name..." ng-change="search(searchText)"/>
    <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="razRecherche()">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <div>HERE THE RADIO BUTTONS</div>
</div>


<div class="table-responsive" id="allContacts">
    <table ng-show="contacts.length" class="table table-striped table-hover spacer">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="colPerson">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('PERSON')">Person</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('PERSON')"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="colCompany">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('COMPANY')">Company</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('COMPANY')"></span>
                </th>
                <th class="colDescription">
                    <a href="" ng-click="personsSort('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')">Description</a>
                    <span class="hSpacer" ng-class="cssChevronsTri('REQUESTDESCRIPTION')"></span>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>       


        <tbody ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText | orderBy:champTri:triDescendant">
            <tr class="clickable">
                <td class="colPerson" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)" ng-class="{sel:selIdx==$index}"><a href="#/view-contacts/{{contact.ID}}">{{contact.PERSON}}</a></td>
                <td class="colCompany" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">{{contact.COMPANY}}</td>
                <td class="colDescription" ng-click="selContact(contact,contact.ID)">{{contact.REQUESTDESCRIPTION}}</td>        
            </tr>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
</div>
```

***My controller***

```
app.controller('ctrlContacts', function ($scope, $timeout, ContactService){

    $scope.search = function(searchText) {
        $scope.reloadPreviousSearch = false;

        if (!searchText.length) {
            //alert("searchText empty");
        }
        if (searchText.length>2) {

            $timeout(function () {
                // RETRIEVE DATA FROM JSON OBJECT OF THE SERVER SEVICE AND A DB QUERY - OK
                ContactService.fastSearch(searchText).success(function(contacts){
                    console.log("query fastSearch OK");                             
                    var length = contacts.length;
                    $scope.loading = false;

                    if (length == 0) {
                        $scope.searchButtonText = "No result";          
                    }else {
                        $scope.searchButtonText = length + " results found";        
                    }
                    // For the orderby date
                    for (var i=0; i<length; i++) {
                        if(contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE!=""){
                            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE = new Date(contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE.replace(/-/g,"/"));
                        }else{
                            contacts[i].REQUESTTRUEDATE=null;
                        }
                    }           

                    $scope.contacts = contacts; 
                    $scope.champTri='PERSON';

                    $scope.selIdx= -1;

                    $scope.selContact=function(contact,idx){
                        $scope.selectedContact=contact;
                        $scope.selIdx=idx;
                        window.location="#/view-contacts/" + idx;
                    }

                    $scope.isSelContact=function(contact){
                        return $scope.selectedContact===contact;
                    }           

                });                                         
            }, 1000);               
        }else{
            $scope.contacts=null;
        }   
    }


    // SEARCH

    $scope.searchText = null;
    $scope.razRecherche = function() {
        $scope.searchText = null;
        $scope.contacts=null;
    }   

    // SORT

    $scope.champTri = null;
    $scope.triDescendant = false;
    $scope.personsSort = function(champ) {
        if ($scope.champTri == champ) {
            $scope.triDescendant = !$scope.triDescendant;
        } else {
            $scope.champTri = champ;
            $scope.triDescendant = false;
        }   
    }

    $scope.cssChevronsTri = function(champ) {
        return {
            glyphicon: $scope.champTri == champ,
            'glyphicon-chevron-up' : $scope.champTri == champ && !$scope.triDescendant,
            'glyphicon-chevron-down' : $scope.champTri == champ && $scope.triDescendant 
        };
    }

});
```

I'm trying to add the radio buttons for filtering the table from the text entered in the text field. But my filter is not working.

Could you please help me to add the filters on the text field (searchText) with the radio button?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: do you want filter for a certain property with radio button?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand right you, you want create a multiple filter by radio buttons

filter property wants an object as parameter

for example you can make in this way:

```
ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:{firstnameProperty:firstnameParamenter, ageProperty:ageParameter}
```

where firstnameProperty is a property on your array object and firstnameParameter is a variable, such as $scope.firstnameParameter
and you can bind to an input.

instead of

```
ng-repeat="contact in contacts | filter:searchText
```

Comment: In fact if I enter "Jea" in the text field, first the system should display all result by default as it's currently done. After if I select the radio button "Person", only the results with the person containing "Jea" should appear. If I click on "company", the radio button "Person" should be unselected and only result with the company containing "Jea" should appear.